# Avoid exception using CopyToDataTable() when no rows are found

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Avoid exception using CopyToDataTable() when no rows are found
I tried this code when no rows found then it gives me error The source contains no DataRows.

```
ds.Tables.Add(dsDecEjID.Tables(0).Select(Cond).CopyToDataTable())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the error, but I'm guessing the select statement is returning null. Can't you use a simple null check?

```
var table = dsDecEjID.Tables(0).Select(Cond);
if(table != null)
    ds.Tables.Add(table.CopyToDataTable());
```

Comment: Looking at [`CopyToDataTable()` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx), it throws a `ArgumentNullException` if the source is null. If it isn't null, then @making3 may be your answer to check the number of rows in the data set.

Comment: table return 0 value so it comes in ds.table.add

Comment: if table have no row found then bind gridview as  with no records.   how can i implement this.

Comment: @Harsh that sounds like a completely different question than what you've asked. You may want to edit this question to clarify if this is the same problem, or ask a new question if it's a different issue completely.

Answer (score 3):

`table != null` not working me, maybe someone like me, my solition is

```
var tableOb = tableMySqlSerialConn.Select(stringSelect);
if (tableOb.Count()>0)
{
tempTable =tableOb.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: This is also the kind of solution I had to do. Even if no rows are returned, the object will not be null.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any rows in the table:

```
If dsDecEjID.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    ds.Tables.Add(dsDecEjID.Tables(0).Select(Cond).CopyToDataTable())
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# 6.0, then you can use:

```
table?.CopyToDataTable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Above null check still gave me an exception. Instead You can use the extension method Any(): to check before using CopyToDataTable() to avoid No Datarow found exception

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> result = <<Some Linq Query>>;

        if (result.Any())
        {
             
        }
```